# Distance from a set of vertices in directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, traversal

I'm designing an algorithm for finding the minimum distance of a given vertex v from a subset of vertices A(that is from an element of this subset).
I need to find the value k such that:

- distance from x to v is k, for some x in A
- distance from y to v is >=k, for all y in A.

My solution consist in:

- getting the transpose graph G'
- visiting G' starting from v, using BFS.
- find the minimum distance from the vertices in A

And I think this works and it should run in O(|V|+|E|) time. 
My question is: there is a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the graph weighted and can it have negative weights?

Comment: No, the graph is not weighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't better solution.

Consider the following: `1-2-3-4`,`A={4}`, `v=1`. you will have to iterate all V,E in the graph [you must read all the path], making this problem `Omega(V+E)`. since your algorithm is correct [simple to prove], and is `O(V+E)` [triviialy, creating G' and BFS], and the problem is `Omega(V+E)`, your solution is optimal, in terms of big O notation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no hope for improving the asymptotic worst case, but a practical optimization is search simultaneously from A and v until the searches meet (always choose to update the smaller frontier).